# How to inherit grandparent CSS not parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, background-image

I have a feeling this won't be possible, but thought I'd ask anyway.

```
<body>                  //body uses 'back' background
<div id="div1">         //div1 uses 'front' background
   <div id="child1">    //child1: no backgrounds, so shows 'front' background
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

- My `body` element uses a background image. (I'll call it the `back` background image)
- `div1` uses a different background image (I'll call it the `front` background image), so the `front` background image covers over the main background image.
- div1 contains a child div `child1` that doesn't use any background images, so it just shows the background image of its parent i.e. it shows the `front` background.

I would like `child1` to use the background of `body` and not the background of its parent `div1`. Because of the nature of the `back` background (it's a drawing, not a repeating pattern), I can't just apply the `back` background image to `child1`. I actually need a way to make a hole in `div1`'s background so that `child1` gets the `back` background image as its background, and not its parent's background.

So my question is: is there a way a div can inherit its grandparent's background, as opposed to its parent's background?

If this isn't possible with CSS, I'm open to javascript solutions.

Comment: I'm not a CSS expert...  that said I don't think it is possible

Comment: A possible (but tedious ) could be, Switching the child and grandchild elements ( body > child1 > div1) and by absolute positioning, place them wherever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be with using javascript and jQuery:

**CSS**

```
body {
   background: url("Background 1");
}
#div1 {
   background: url("Background 2");
}
#child1 {
   background: url("Background 1");
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

  function positionBackground() {

     var myChild1   = $("#child1");
     myChild1.css({
        backgroundPosition : "-" + myChild1.offset().left + "px -" + myChild1.offset().top + "px"
     });
  }

  positionBackground();

  $(window).resize(positionBackground);
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gMK9G/

Comment: Now we're talking. Thanks ced-b, and happy offsetting.

Answer (score 0):

> **UPDATE** 2 Elements in the DOM Cannot share the same background image, you can maybe apply the background image and position them exactly so that it looks like they are, but in reality it is not possible.

As far as I am aware **this is not currently possible** because css only has inherit and inherit "inherits" from it's parents and there is no way to customize that. Of course javascript can do this easily and I will provide a jQuery example only because you have the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tag.

```
$('.inherit-grandparent').each(function( element ) {
    var $this = $(this),
        property = $this.attr('grandparent-property'),
        value = $this.parent().parent().css(property);
    if(property && value) $this.css(property, value);
});
```

**Usage**

```
<div class="inherit-grandparent" grandparent-property="background"></div>
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aKHfr/**

> So not only will this solve your problem, but it's dynamic so you can use it on any element and request any property.

**Update:**

> Here is a jQuery Plugin version, if you would prefer that.

```
jQuery.fn.inheritGrandparent = function( property ) {
    var $this = $(this),
        value = $this.parent().parent().css(property);
    if(property && value) $this.css(property, value);
};
```

**Usage:**

```
$('#test').inheritGrandparent('background');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aKHfr/2/**

> ## <strike>Happy Coding!</strike>

Comment: This solution unfortunately doesn't work for the type of image I described in my question. All the javascript does is it sets the css property with js instead of manually. But it's the exact same result as setting the child1's background to the same value as the grandparent's background. The browser will layout an independent background image inside child1, and won't "share" the grandparent's background. See this jsfiddle to get my point. http://jsfiddle.net/aKHfr/4/ It just renders the same image again.

Comment: Ok, well in this case then. it is not possible with CSS or Javascript. I've never heard of such. 2 Elements cannot share the same background image. What do you think inherit does? it doesn't share the same background at all. it copies it over.

Comment: No. It's definitely not possible with CSS OR JAVASCRIPT. 2 Elements cannot Share the same background.

Comment: And your edit was rejected. you cannot just randomly add your own comments to someone's question/answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to change the way that styles are inherited, that said, you shouldn't really need to.

This is a little rough, but you could use the same image on the child div as you're using on the body and just play with the background positioning to line it up.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QsrCv/2/)**

```
body {
    background: url("Background 1");
}
#div1 {
    background: url("Background 2");
}
#child1 {
    background: url("Background 1");
    background-position: 0px -125px; /* adjust as needed */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My HTML:

```
  <div class="p1">
       <div class="p2">
         <div class="p3">
           GandSOn
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

My css:

```
    .p1 {
disapley: flex;
}

.p2{
display:inherit;
}

.p3 {
display:inherit;
}
```