# Make div not to inherit style from parent div

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Is there a way to make a div not inherit style from a parent div?

**For example (part of our template code):**

```
<a data-field="friendsLink"><b>Friends</b></a>
```

The goal is to keep `<b>` tag style and not inherit the anchor tag style, i.e font and font-color.

Comment: Could you set the font color as you want them on the inner element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheriting (some) parent styles is part of css spec. You'll be best served to embrace it and use specificity to declare styles to override the parent styles:

```
a {
    parent styles here;
}

a b {
    style overrides here;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the styles will always be inherited. The only way to make the inner div have other styles is to explicitly override them with new declarations.

In some cases the new declarations can be of type `font: initial`, but in your case I don't think you have a choice but to reset the styles to what you want.

This question also already has an answer here: [How to inherit grandparent css, not parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543810/how-to-inherit-grandparent-css-not-parent). They have some additional suggestions using JavaScript to copy the styles. But for my money overriding it is easier, at least if it's only a few.